# What are the patterns for performing sequential work with GTK-style async APIs in C

Tags: c, asynchronous, gtk, synchronous, glib

The APIs I'm working with right now (libnm specifically) have many of the synchronous calls labeled as deprecated with the asynchronous calls the preferred way to use the API.  These are 'gtk-style asynchronous methods which take the form of `operation_async( <args>, <callback fptr> )` with a callback then processing `operation_finish()` and I guess updating some (global or heap, passed as "user data") system state.

What are the preferred patterns for writing readable code when using an API like this in C?

Do I just ignore the deprecated tags and use the synchronous calls (preferably in a worker thread)?

Do I make a string of 'breadcrumb' callbacks which each call `operation_n+1_async( <args>, <callback n+1)`?

Do I make manually synchronize to a series of callbacks using a mutex or similar for each so that I can keep most of the code in one worker function (probably in it's own thread) written in sequential order and just block it until the dependent operations complete?

edit: Further reading from [Gnome documentation on "main contexts"](https://developer.gnome.org/documentation/tutorials/main-contexts.html) suggests maybe starting a worker thread which has it's own main loop (or copy of the main loop? not sure on my read).  The callbacks can then quit the main loop when the last one terminates, each returning their data to the worker thread.  For further stages the worker thread can simply restart the main loop with the state it has in the stack and new `_async()` calls.

Is there some other pattern entirely?

And does GLIB/GIO provide some macros or pre-built callbacks to make one of these patterns simpler to run.

Comment: Ignoring deprecated function is not the way to go. If these functions have been marked as deprecated, then that means that they will get removed eventually. It's giving you time to adjust the code so when they are gone, your code does still work.

Comment: "Do I make manually synchronize to a series of callbacks using a mutex" async usually runs with a single thread, so a mutex is in the case pointless. I only have experience with async in Javascript in Python where there is native constructs to yield your current task to the async control group, I've never used async in C before. I'm afraid, you will have to use series of callbacks.

Comment: In this case the synchronization would again be to a worker thread.  I assume a worker thread is probably the only way to write a compound task as a single piece of code in anything with a UI.  Or at least the only way to do it unstrangled.

Comment: I don't know about a separate thread. One of the points of async is that you run all in a single thread thus avoiding of the need of structures like mutex, semaphores etc. which make thread synchronization tricky in the first place. Like I said, I've never done async directly in C so I don't know the best practices here, I suppose the the documentation of  your library (`libnm`) might have a chapter about best practices.

Comment: My mental model has been to think of callbacks as ISRs.  In which case they would be only 'technically' not a different thread, but still a different line of execution.  Do you mean that all the callbacks in an event loop multi-task cooperatively (with the next callback only running after the last completed) so a new callback never interrupts another?

Comment: I don't know how `libnm` does async, so I cannot answer that. You would need to look it up in the manual. Usually you'll find there how to effectively use the API and best practices.

Comment: Unfortunately no.  The manual just contains a screed on why synchronous calls are deprecated and assumes you are already a familiar glib/gtk programmer who knows how to use _async() calls.

Comment: In that case I would tag this question with the correct tag to narrow down the number of people seeing this question. At the moment your tag are too generic. If the project has a github repo, I would also post an issue asking for an user guide with the async methods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248547/discussion-between-davolfman-and-pablo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the Gnome tutorial on asynchronous programming](https://developer.gnome.org/documentation/tutorials/asynchronous-programming.html#operations-in-series) the first option is definitely one of the strategies, with a twist:

If you prototype the callback functions you can then write them in order after the function with the first call.  This turns them from a seemingly-unrelated set of functions that takes effort to connect into a 'single' long procedure which is broken up into several coroutines.  There's more boilerplate than I'd like but it meets the goals of being readable and relatively easy to implement.

With heavy paraphrasing and simplification this example is something like this:

```
static void my_operation_cb1 (GObject *source_object, GAsyncResult *result, gpointer user_data);
static void my_operation_cb2 (GObject *source_object, GAsyncResult *result, gpointer user_data);
static void my_operation_cb3 (GObject *source_object, GAsyncResult *result, gpointer user_data);

static void my_operation (MyObject *self)
{
  <perform setup>
  api_operation1_async (<arg>, <cancellable>, my_operation_cb1, self);
}

static void my_operation_cb1 (GObject *source_object, GAsyncResult *result, gpointer user_data)
{
  rc = api_operation1_finish (<arg>, result, NULL, &error);

  processed_result=process_1(result);

  g_socket_client_connect_async (processed_result, <cancellable>, my_operation_cb2, self);
}

static void my_operation_cb2 (GObject *source_object, GAsyncResult *result, gpointer user_data)
{
  rc = api_operation1_finish (<arg>, result, NULL, &error);

  processed_result=process2(result);

  g_socket_client_connect_async (processed_result, <cancellable>, my_operation_cb3, self);
}

static void my_operation_cb3 (GObject *source_object, GAsyncResult *result, gpointer user_data)
{
  rc = api_operation1_finish (<arg>, result, NULL, &error);

  overall_result = process3(result);

}
```

The user data can be a pointer to a common structure which will allow state to be passed between the various callbacks of the process so they don't require global variables.

Particularly if multiple operations need to be completed before another asynchronous call is run with their results a completion count or flag set (along with any needed results of course) can be added to the user data struct and checked at the end of these callbacks.  When the last callback of one of these sets finds the others have completed it can run the next asynchronous call in the chain.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding updating system state, it doesn't need to be global - you pass it from one callback to another using the `user_data` parameter.

For example:

```
struct CallbackData {
  MyObject *self;
  int field;
  ...
}
static void my_operation (MyObject *self) {
  struct CallbackData *data = g_new0(struct CallbackData, 1);
  data->self = self;
  data->field = 42;
  operation_async(..., (GAsyncReadyCallback)callback1, data);
}
static void callback1 (GObject *source, GAsyncResult *res, struct CallbackData *data) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Makes sense.  Does require creating a new class in the gobject system though, right?

Comment: CallbackData doesn't have to be a class.

Comment: I was reading gpointer as if it was an alias to gobject*  I didn't realize it was literally a void pointer.